# disable button depending up response from redux

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux

I currently show modals depending upon the `updateReminderResponse` object.

At the moment, you can click the submit button multiple times.

How can I disabled the button when the button is clicked, until `UpdateVehicleReminder` and `saveNotifications` have resolved, and aswell as `updateReminderResponses` as defined:

```
const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);

const onSubmit = async () => {
  const success = await tryBiometrics();
  if (success) {
    setdisabled(true);
    ...
 
    tagNotifications(state);
    dispatch(
      UpdateVehicleReminder(
        ...
      )
    );
    try {
      await saveNotifications(state.notificationList);
    } catch (e) {
      logger.error("Error saving notifications", e);
      throw e;
    }
  }

  setdisabled(false);
};

const disableSubmit =
  disabled && typeof updateReminderResponses !== "undefined" ? true : false;

<Button
  title="example"
  buttonStyle={[buttons.primary]}
  titleStyle={buttons.primaryTitle}
  onPress={() => onSubmit()}
  disabled={disableSubmit} // disable until updateReminderResponse is defined
/>;
{
  updateReminderResponse && updateReminderResponse.updateFailure && (
    <MessageModals showModal callback={closeFailModal} />
  );
}
{
  updateReminderResponse && updateReminderResponse.success && (
    <MessageModals
      showModal
      successTick
      modalBody={myVehiclesCmsContent.updateRemindersSuccessMessage}
      callback={closeSuccessModal}
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't track the disabled condition in the state. It only depends on the value of `updateReminderResponses`.

Just test that variable.

```
<Button ... disabled={typeof updateReminderResponses === 'undefined'}
```

Comment: Thankyou i have updated my aswer, its still not quite right

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ref to keep the button pressed state. It won't disable the button but can control submitting multiple times.

Make sure to set the pressed ref to false when you needed.

```
const pressed = useRef(false);



const onSubmit = async () => {
  if(!pressed.current){
     pressed.current = true
     // your code
  }
};
```